# Restore Gemfile.lock from gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gemfile

In my Rails App, Gemfile.lock is ignored from the tracking through the .gitignore

But I want the file to be committed and tracked.

How do I do that?

Comment: Remove it from .gitignore?

Comment: Yeah, If I remove the Gemfile.lock form .gitignore file, then it shows .gitignore as modified but I dont see the Gemfile.lock in the modified list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the entry for Gemfile.lock from the .gitignore, add the .gitignore and commit. Then add and commit the Gemfile.lock. As long as these are done in two separate commits, other team members will also be able to track the Gemfile.lock file.